# Calculate the standard deviation from a binned list

Tags: excel, math, statistics

Say I have a list of integer values, `1` through `10`. Instead of having the actual dataset, I just have the quantities of each value. For example:

```
1  | 73
2  | 121
3  | 155
4  | 149
5  | 187
6  | 180
7  | 166
8  | 148
9  | 120
10 | 81
```

As you can see, it'd be incredibly time consuming to list out each value individually (73 `1`s, 121 `2`s et cetera) but it's the only way I know how to use STDEV().

How can I calculate the standard deviation of the values?

Comment: Perhaps here: http://www.real-statistics.com/descriptive-statistics/frequency-tables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible alternative, assuming `1` is in A1, in C1:

```
=B1*(A1-SUMPRODUCT(A$1:A$10,B$1:B$10)/SUM(B$1:B$10))^2
```

copied down to C10. In B11, copied across to C11:

```
=SUM(B1:B10)
```

In D11:

```
=SQRT(C11/(B11-1))
```

- if `2.520979` is the wrong answer, forget the above!

Excel uses:

[image: SO32854049 example]

to compute [STDEV](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-function-51fecaaa-231e-4bbb-9230-33650a72c9b0) and the above just breaks this down into steps to match the data format available.

Answer (score 0):

A custom User Defined Function (aka UDF) might be the most expedient route.

[image: UDF for exploding array in STDEV]

Your values from column A have been exploded to the multiples in column B into D2:D1381 (see below).

The [STDEV](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-function-51FECAAA-231E-4BBB-9230-33650A72C9B0), [STDEV.P](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-P-function-6E917C05-31A0-496F-ADE7-4F4E7462F285) and [STDEV.S](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-S-function-7D69CF97-0C1F-4ACF-BE27-F3E83904CC23) formulas in E2:G2 are,

```
=STDEV($D2:$D1381)
=STDEV.P($D2:$D1381)
=STDEV.S($D2:$D1381)
```

The UDF formulas in E3:G3 are,

```
=udf_STDEV_Exploded($A2:$A11, 1)   ' or =udf_STDEV_Exploded($A2:$A11)
=udf_STDEV_Exploded($A2:$A11, 2)
=udf_STDEV_Exploded($A2:$A11, 3)
```

The UDF formulas are based upon the following module code.

```
Function udf_STDEV_Exploded(rng As Range, Optional iTYP As Long = 1)
    Dim r As Long, v As Long, vVALs As Variant

    ReDim vVALs(0)
    For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For v = 1 To rng.Cells(r, 2).Value2
            vVALs(UBound(vVALs)) = rng.Cells(r, 1).Value2
            ReDim Preserve vVALs(0 To UBound(vVALs) + 1)
        Next v
    Next r
    ReDim Preserve vVALs(0 To UBound(vVALs) - 1)

    Select Case iTYP
        Case 1
            udf_STDEV_Exploded = WorksheetFunction.StDev(vVALs)
        Case 2
            udf_STDEV_Exploded = WorksheetFunction.StDev_P(vVALs)
        Case 3
            udf_STDEV_Exploded = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(vVALs)
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
End Function
```

I've added an option to process the array using either [STDEV](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-function-51FECAAA-231E-4BBB-9230-33650A72C9B0), [STDEV.P](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-P-function-6E917C05-31A0-496F-ADE7-4F4E7462F285) or [STDEV.S](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-S-function-7D69CF97-0C1F-4ACF-BE27-F3E83904CC23) functions. The **STDEV** function is the default.

**Addendum**

The code for exploding the values from A2:B11 into a long column of values on the worksheet is,

```
Sub stdev_vals()
    Dim rw As Long, f As Long, n As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, 1) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the average (here labeled as THE_AVG):

```
=SUM(BIN_NUM*REPEATS)/SUM(REPEATS)
```

entered as an array formula (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER). Then calculate the standard deviation:

```
=SQRT(SUM((BIN_NUM-THE_AVG)^2*REPEATS)/(SUM(REPEATS)-1))
```

again entered as an array formula. If desired, the two calculations can be collapsed into a single formula:

```
=SQRT(SUM((BIN_NUM-SUM(BIN_NUM*REPEATS)/SUM(REPEATS))^2*REPEATS)/(SUM(REPEATS)-1))
```

In these formulas BIN_NUM represents the range of cells with the bin numbers (say A1:A10) and REPEATS represents the range of cells with the counts in each bin (say B1:B10).

Hope that helps